# Laravel 8 - Get image url from images saved in storage folder

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel Framework 8.62.0` and save uploaded images like the following:

```
            $contents = file_get_contents($imgUrl);
            // $file_name = basename($url_upper);
            $file_name = strtolower(substr($imgUrl, strrpos($imgUrl, '/') + 1));
            $strg = Storage::disk('public_collectible_img')->put($file_name, $contents);
```

My `public_collectible_img`-driver looks like the following:

```
        'public_collectible_img' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/collectibles_img'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/collectible/image',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

When I try to open the following url localy I get a `404`-error.

`http://localhost/my_project/public/collectible/image/1.jpg`

The image exists in the folder:

[image]

How to access the image and what is the correct url?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: you are missing storage in url

Comment: did you publish storage link? I mean this: `php artisan storage:link`. if you did then address it like this : `http://localhost/storage/collectible/image/1.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the a symbolic link between "storage" and "public" folder

> To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a
> symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public.

Run the following artisan code:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk